Get Windows 10 Update history as plain text in terminal?
I just had to waste my time finding out about this, and wanted to document it, so here is the formal question:
How can I get the Windows Update history as a plain text list, of one update per line, printed to terminal?

I truly hate wasting my time for free, to help out those parasites at Microsoft that make billions of dollars; but I'm consoling myself that after all, all I'm trying is to help myself and avoid waste of my time in the future (after all, I cannot count on any help, especially not from Microsoft). So anyways, this is what sort of ended up working for me - in Administator PowerShell:
PS C:\tmp> Get-WUHistory -MaxDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -Last 4 | Select ComputerName,Operationname,Result,Date,Title | ConvertTo-Csv
#TYPE Selected.System.__ComObject
"ComputerName","OperationName","Result","Date","Title"
"DESKTOP-_MY_PC_","Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:52:34 AM","Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.419.433.0) - Current Channel (Broad)"
"DESKTOP-_MY_PC_","Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:52:14 AM","Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.419.428.0) - Current Channel (Broad)"
"DESKTOP-_MY_PC_","Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:20:42 AM","Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.419.422.0) - Current Channel (Broad)"
"DESKTOP-_MY_PC_","Installation","Succeeded","2024-10-10 10:20:29 AM","2024-10 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 22H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5044273)"

This is not exactly readable, however its closest to being readable for me. What else you'll find on the net:


https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/failed-how-can-i-copy-entire-view-update-history/d240da60-92af-47eb-86c9-16912613da03

They suggest wmic qfe, however it prints something like this:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic qfe
Caption                                     CSName           Description      FixComments  HotFixID   InstallDate  InstalledBy          InstalledOn  Name  ServicePackInEffect  Status
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=5044029  DESKTOP-_MY_PC_  Update                        KB5044029               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/10/2024
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=5027122  DESKTOP-_MY_PC_  Update                        KB5027122               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  6/13/2023
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4560366  DESKTOP-_MY_PC_  Security Update               KB4560366               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/13/2020
http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4561600  DESKTOP-_MY_PC_  Security Update               KB4561600               NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/13/2020
...

So, for one, it isn't sorted by date, for another, as they mention in the post:

... it does not report the update 'Status' ("Successful"/"Failed").
... Some of the updates that failed are not listed by 'wmic qfe'!


Then there is:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-logs

... which says:

To merge and convert Windows Update trace files (.etl files) into a single readable WindowsUpdate.log file, see Get-WindowsUpdateLog.

So, again in Administrator PowerShell:
PS C:\tmp> Get-WindowsUpdateLog

Converting C:\WINDOWS\logs\WindowsUpdate into C:\Users\USER\Desktop\WindowsUpdate.log ...


    Directory: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\WindowsUpdateLog


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        2024-10-10   8:10 PM                SymCache

Input
----------------
File(s):
     C:\WINDOWS\logs\WindowsUpdate\WindowsUpdate.20241009.193738.504.2.etl
     C:\WINDOWS\logs\WindowsUpdate\WindowsUpdate.20241009.193738.504.3.etl
...
WindowsUpdate.log written to C:\Users\USER\Desktop\WindowsUpdate.log


Unfortunately, this WindowsUpdate.log an EXTREMELY verbose log:
2024-10-09 19:37:59.5774746 11244 20716 Agent           * END * Finding updates CallerId = Update;ScanForUpdates, Id = 8, Exit code = 0x00000000 (cV = DHII9XnqGUeFvAf4.1.0.1.0.0.1)
2024-10-09 19:37:59.5816894 11244 20716 IdleTimer       WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 9) started; operation # 49; does not use network; is at background priority
2024-10-09 19:37:59.5912806 11244 20716 Agent           * START * Finding updates CallerId = Update;ScanForUpdates  Id = 9 (cV = DHII9XnqGUeFvAf4.1.0.1.0.0.2.1)
2024-10-09 19:37:59.5912828 11244 20716 Agent           Online = No; Interactive = No; AllowCachedResults = No; Ignore download priority = No
2024-10-09 19:37:59.5912835 11244 20716 Agent           Criteria = IsInstalled=0 AND AppCategoryIDs contains '64b22df1-5a9c-4c88-aa1f-42cefaf8b281'""
2024-10-09 19:37:59.5912862 11244 20716 Agent           ServiceID = {855E8A7C-ECB4-4CA3-B045-1DFA50104289} Third party service
...

... and any success/failure report is connected to GUIDs, not names of updates, so you'd have to write your own program to parse this and output readable plain text.

Then there is

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70762060/difference-between-wua-iupdatesearcher-and-wmic-qfe

... which points out:

I am trying to figure out what are the differences between WUA
(Windows Update Agent API) IupdateSearcher and wmic qfe list.
When I use WUA IupdateSearcher I get these updates:
(New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session).CreateUpdateSearcher().Search('IsInstalled=1').Updates

| Format-Table -AutoSize
And when using wmic qfe list:
wmic qfe list brief

The latter includes updates that the former doesn't and vice versa.
Why is that?

So, I thought, no point in bothering with Microsoft.Update.Session either ...

I got a hint for PowerShell Get-WUHistory from:

https://serverfault.com/questions/962728/getting-sensible-information-out-of-windows-update-log

However, this is not trivial either: if I run just Get-WUHistory, then after dumping whatever data, the PowerShell cmdlet freezes; and in spite of:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098120/stop-a-long-running-ps-cmdlet

... suggesting

Using Ctrl+C or CTRL + Break should stop any command

... Ctrl+C doesn't stop this command when it freezes, and so you have to close the PowerShell window to kill it.
Thankfully, there is this:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/get-wuhistory-freezes/m-p/1410640

... where it is mentioned:

It looks like there's an infinite loop when the -Last parameter is not specified. So I'm working around this problem by making sure I specify -Last 100. The command reliably stops in that case.
Here's a full example for clarity:
Get-WUHistory -MaxDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -Last 100


Cool, now it stops - however, it truncates the lines according to the character width of the PowerShell terminal:
PS C:\tmp> Get-WUHistory -MaxDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -Last 4

ComputerName Operationname  Result     Date                Title
------------ -------------  ------     ----                -----
DESKTOP-_... Installation   Succeeded  2024-10-10 10:52... Security Intellige...
DESKTOP-_... Installation   Succeeded  2024-10-10 10:52... Security Intellige...
DESKTOP-_... Installation   Succeeded  2024-10-10 10:20... Security Intellige...
DESKTOP-_... Installation   Succeeded  2024-10-10 10:20... 2024-10 Cumulative...

... and this holds even if you redirect the output to a file, Get-WUHistory -MaxDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -Last 4 > .\hist.txt
In this link:

https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7vinz2/how_to_get_all_info_still_in_a_list_or_table/

... this is mentioned:

 Get-WUHistory | Select Property1, Property2

Will select only those (properties). If you want to force it to be a table:
 Get-WUHistory | Select Property1, Property2 | Format-Table -AutoSize


However, it turns out it is Format-Table itself that truncates! Then,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49122925/how-do-i-use-format-table-without-truncation-of-values

... mentions that to avoid truncation of values, you have to:

Pipe to Out-File -Width with a sufficiently large value (don't use [int]::MaxValue, though, because every line of tabular output gets padded to that very width)

... which I find amazingly stupid; thankfully someone else suggests:

I suggest using Export-CSV instead of using any of the Format-* commands to output to a file in your situation.

But I want to output to terminal, not export to a file, and so this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55921369/equivalent-of-export-csv-to-write-output

... suggests:

You should use the ConvertTo-CSV cmdlet if you want to convert objects to CSV and return the result to stdout, instead of a file.
...
You'll find most builtin Export- cmdlets have a ConvertTo- equivalent.

... and that is how I arrived at the "winning" command.
What a waste of time this has been; what a shitty, shitty operating system! Looking forward to the day I'll never have to deal with it again ...

A diatribe is not useful, nor a prolix, periphrastic, pleonastic response. That said (though I have some sympathy for sentiments you expressed), there are other OS's. Are you constrained by conditions of employment from employing another?
